# Strange performance results -- loop vs list comprehension and zip()

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension

I had a really simple problem and got some strange results when I tried to figure out which solution is faster.

The original Problem: Given two lists `ListA`, `ListB` and a constant `k`, remove all entries where the two lists sum to `k`.

I solved the problem in two ways: First I tried using a loop and then I used list comprehension and `zip()` to zip and unzip the two lists.

The version using a loop.

```py
def Remove_entries_simple(listA, listB, k):
    """ removes entries that sum to k """
    new_listA = []
    new_listB = []
    for index in range(len(listA)):
        if listA[index] + listB[index] == k:
            pass
        else:
            new_listA.append(listA[index])
            new_listB.append(listB[index])
    return(new_listA, new_listB)
```

The version using list comprehension and `zip()`

```py
def Remove_entries_zip(listA, listB, k):
    """ removes entries that sum to k using zip"""
    zip_lists = [(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(listA, listB) if not (a+b) == k]

    # unzip the lists
    new_listA, new_listB = zip(*zip_lists)
    return(list(new_listA), list(new_listB))
```

Then I tried to determine which approach is faster. But then I got what you see in figure below (x-axis: size of the lists, y-axis: average time to run it,  10**3 repetitions). For some reason the version using `zip()` always makes the same jump at somewhat the same position -- I ran it multiple times and on different machines. Can someone explain what could cause such an odd behavior?

[image: Plot comparing running times]

Update: The code I used to generate the plot. I used a function decorator to run each problem a 1000 times.

import statements:

```
import random
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The function decorator:

```
def Repetition_Decorator(fun, Rep=10**2):
    ''' returns the average over Rep repetitions'''
    def Return_function(*args, **kwargs):
        Start_time = time.clock()
        for _ in range(Rep):
            fun(*args, **kwargs)
        return (time.clock() - Start_time)/Rep

return Return_function
```

The code to create the plots:

```
Zippedizip = []
Loops = []
The_Number = 10
Size_list = list(range(10, 1000, 10))

Repeated_remove_loop = Repetition_Decorator(Remove_entries_simple, Rep=10**3)
Repeated_remove_zip = Repetition_Decorator(Remove_entries_zip, Rep=10**3)

for size in Size_list:
    ListA = [random.choice(range(10)) for _ in range(size)]
    ListB = [random.choice(range(10)) for _ in range(size)]

    Loops.append(Repeated_remove_loop(ListA, ListB, The_Number))
    Zippedizip.append(Repeated_remove_zip(ListA, ListB, The_Number))

plt.xlabel('Size of List')
plt.ylabel('Averaged time in seconds')
plt.plot(Size_list, Loops, label="Using Loop")
plt.plot(Size_list, Zippedizip, label="Zip")
plt.legend(loc='upper left', shadow=False, fontsize='x-large')
plt.show()
```

Update-Update: thanks to kaya3 for pointing out the timeit module.

To be as close as possible to my original code but also use the timeit module, I created a new function decorator that uses the timeit module for timing the code.

The new decorator:

```
def Repetition_Decorator_timeit(fun, Rep=10**2):                                                                                   
"""returns average over Rep repetitions with timeit"""                                                                         
    def Return_function(*args, **kwargs):                                                                                          
        partial_fun = lambda: fun(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                 
        return timeit.timeit(partial_fun, number=Rep) / Rep                                                                        
return Return_function
```

When I use the new decorator the version using the for loop is not affected but the `zip` version no longer makes the jump.

[image]

So far I feel quite certain that the jump is a result of how I measure the function rather than the function itself.  But the jump is so distinct -- always at the same list size across different machines -- that it cannot be a fluke. Any ideas why exactly this jump happens?

Update-Update-Update:

It has something to do with the garbage collector, because if I disable the garbage collector with `gc.disable()`, both ways of measuring give the same result.

[image: Garbage Collector disabled]

**What did I learn here:** Do not just measure the time of execution yourself. Use the `timeit` module for measuring performance of code snippets.

Comment: Interesting; please could you also include the code you used to analyse it?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the behaviour myself; the version using `zip` is consistently about 30% faster, for sizes from 100 up to 10,000.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3? It matters because the whole thing should be probably be done using iterators anyway.  There's nothing in this problem that should require you to create any temporary lists. You really want to pipe 2 parallel lists through a couple of processing functions (to drop based on your criteria) and then out the other end.  If you are using py2 here, then you are creating quite a few temporary lists with your current implementation.

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.8.

Comment: @kaya3 added the code to generate the plots. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar pattern, but zip remains faster. Python 3.7 on macOS: https://i.imgur.com/WpNXsTI.png

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an artifact of the way you have measured the running times. I do not know what causes your timing code to produce this effect, but the effect disappears when I use `timeit` to measure the running times instead. I'm using Python 3.6.2.

I can consistently reproduce the effect using your timing code; I get the `zip` version's running time jumping at around the same threshold, though it is still slightly faster than the other version on my machine:

[image: Timed using clock]

However, when I measure the times using `timeit`, the effect disappears completely:

[image]

Here's the code using `timeit`; I changed as little as possible from your analysis code.

```py
import timeit

Zippedizip = []
Loops = []
The_Number = 10
Size_list = list(range(10, 1000, 10))
Reps = 1000

for size in Size_list:
    ListA = [random.choice(range(10)) for _ in range(size)]
    ListB = [random.choice(range(10)) for _ in range(size)]

    remove_loop = lambda: Remove_entries_simple(ListA, ListB, The_Number)
    remove_zip = lambda: Remove_entries_zip(ListA, ListB, The_Number)

    Loops.append(timeit.timeit(remove_loop, number=Reps) / Reps)
    Zippedizip.append(timeit.timeit(remove_zip, number=Reps) / Reps)

# ...
```

So I think it's a spurious result. That said, I don't understand what's causing it in your timing code. I tried simplifying your timing code to not use a decorator or vargs, and I replaced `time.clock()` with `time.perf_counter()` which is more accurate, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I put the `timeit` function into a decorator and the effect vanishes. I still do not know why the other decorator consistently makes this jump appear.

Answer (score 0):

A version that uses zip to iterate in parallel through the lists while using append for the sums seems to be more consistent.

I think what we're seeing with `zip(*...)` is that splatting (`*`) iterables into argument lists has some threshold (768 arguments maybe?) after which a slower method comes to play.

```
def Remove_entries_halfzip(listA, listB, k):
    """ removes entries that sum to k using zip"""
    new_listA = []
    new_listB = []
    for a, b in zip(listA, listB):
        if a + b != k:
            new_listA.append(a)
            new_listB.append(b)

    return (new_listA, new_listB)
```

[image: Chart]

You can further micro-optimize things by making the append functions locals, saving an attribute lookup for each iteration:

```py
def Remove_entries_halfzip_micro_opt(listA, listB, k):
    """ removes entries that sum to k using zip"""
    new_listA = []
    new_listB = []
    append_a = new_listA.append
    append_b = new_listB.append
    for a, b in zip(listA, listB):
        if a + b != k:
            append_a(a)
            append_b(b)

    return (new_listA, new_listB)
```

[image]

I also tried a Numpy implementation, but it was slower due to the data conversions needed (`np.array()` casts on every invocation). If you're working with Numpy arrays through and through, it will be faster.